# Boot Ubuntu from Multi Partition USB drive

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, usb, partitioning

I have an USB that is of 3 partitions G:\, H:\ and I:\

Both G:\ and H:\ are write protected. I have recently installed Ubuntu 13 in I:\ drive using the USB Installer.

I would like to Try Ubuntu before using it. When i reboot my PC, the USB is not detected.
I have set the settings `Boot from USB devices enabled` and `Boot USB devices first` in the BIOS settings.

Still the USB was not being detected. I cannot see `Press any key to boot from USB` there.

**Disk management screenshot**
[image: Here is the link for the screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the boot flag is set on the correct partition, then open the boot options menu, USB should be on that list, and you should be able to boot just fine.

The universal installer should have done this already, but if it didn't you can use gparted or any other partition manager to set the flag.

In the start up of the machine, pressing F9 F10 or ESC can allow you to enter the boot menu.

Comment: I don't use Windows for this stuff very much, but from what I can see you can use diskmgmt.msc to set bootable flags.  (go to the run dialog, windows button+r and type in diskmgmt.msc from there you can set the flag on any drive that is connected)

Comment: I couldn't see setting the boot flag in disk management. Additional info: (The status of the drive is Active.)

Comment: Ok, did you reboot, and try to enter the boot options menu?
That is generally an F key, depending on your BIOS, and it will give you the option to select where you're booting from.  If the drive is listed as active, then that is the drive with the bootable flag

Comment: I did the reboot,I found an option called USB2.0 but it didn't work.

Comment: did you install ubuntu 13 to the disk, or did you create a bootdisk out of the empty partition?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9601/discussion-between-eric-and-igo4it)

Comment: Try to boot on another pc. If you can't, your USB key is not bootable.

Comment: @Eric I don't have enough rep to chat! :(

Comment: I have formatted the partition with FAT32 and did it again. But it is in vain. :(